# MVC3 pattern - content versioning options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, versioning

What are elegant approaches for versioning of static content in the web. I work on a project which previously used xml/xslt to achieve this currently. The version number is than retrieved from a parser and used.

How can I achieve version-ing. If I choose to move away from xml/xslt and use partial views to display static content?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this way. It is better to build a dynamic page to display the static content. and all the different versions are stored in the database.

In this way, you can retrieve a certain version quite easily and it is also easy to manage the data.

Comment: I understand that db is better. But what if we can't use a DB to store the markup?

Comment: I see. How about this: build an action to accept the version parameter. And in the action, use the version parameter to redirect to the corresponding static content. You keep all versions of the static content in different files

Answer (score 0):

If you want have old version just for your purpose, easily use some SVN... If you want provide all versions of document on your page:

1. Use xml/xslt or DB
2. In your Action set OutputCache attribute for caching content for long time

More about caching: [MVC caching and performance](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)